# Временной ряд. Как после изменение частоты и групперовки получить данные из конкретной строки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть временной ряд с данными OHLCV (открытие, максимум, минимум, закрытие, значение). Начальная частота 15 минут.
Необходимо изменить частоту до 1 часа.
Данные OHLC получаются замечательно стандартными методами Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Open':[92.228, 91.951, 91.434, 91.286, 91.372, 91.353, 91.382, 91.444],
'High':[92.228, 91.974, 91.512, 91.432, 91.400, 91.385, 91.546, 91.535],
'Low':[91.939, 91.327, 91.148, 91.182, 91.177, 91.301, 91.336, 91.414],
'Close':[91.954, 91.437, 91.284, 91.374, 91.355, 91.382, 91.446, 91.513],
'Volume':[1537.44, 4314.3, 3489.17, 4070.41, 2800.4, 2545.31, 2584.55, 1813.96]}
 
index = pd.date_range('2021-04-22 09:00', periods=8, freq='15min')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index = index)

conversion = {'Open' : 'first', 'High' : 'max', 'Low' : 'min', 'Close' : 'last'}

df2 = df1.resample('H').agg(conversion)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить значение из колонки Volume из соответствующей строки для максимального и минимального значения.
Как постарался показать на рисунке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def vol_high(df):
    return df.loc[df["High"].idxmax(), "Volume"]

def vol_low(df):
    return df.loc[df["Low"].idxmin(), "Volume"]

grp = df1.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="H", key="index"))

res = (df2
       .join(grp.apply(vol_high).to_frame("Volume_High"))
       .join(grp.apply(vol_low).to_frame("Volume_Low")))
```

результат:

```
In [88]: res
Out[88]:
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume_High  Volume_Low
2021-04-22 09:00:00  92.228  92.228  91.148  91.374      1537.44     3489.17
2021-04-22 10:00:00  91.372  91.546  91.177  91.513      2584.55     2800.40
```